# ggsn scale bar issue

Tags: r, ggmap

I'm hoping to get some help with the ggsn scale bar for my ggmap figure. 
I am having trouble resizing the scale bar. The text is overlaying the line and I can't resize it into the filled in bar.

I've tried adjusting the height,st.size, and st.dist  parameters, but these don't seem to change the scale bar.

I'd appreciate any insights. Could this be due to the extreme zoomed in scale of my ggmap?

[image: Current map version]

```
MAD_map <-  ggmap(get_map(location=c(-89.410087,43.074243), zoom=14, scale=4, source = "stamen", maptype = "terrain")) +theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),            axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                   axis.text.y=element_blank(),axis.ticks.y=element_blank() ) +

  ggsn::scalebar(x.min = -89.387949, x.max = -89.387952, 
                 y.min =43.090330, y.max = 43.090340,location="topright", 
                 dist = .5, dd2km = TRUE, model = "GRS80", height =.2, st.size = 4, st.dist = .1

                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I didn't understand the underlying logic of the y.min and y.max variables.  I nudged the y.max variable up, looking back my variables were on top of each other. I guess I should've mapped out the Coordinates for my rectangle on google maps would have saved me alot of time.